# Individual timeout in nose multiprocessing plugin

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have started using nose to run tests. I discovered the multiprocessing plugin has a timeout, that I can change on the command line.

Is there a way to extend the timeout for individual tests (in the test code) so I don't have a massive global timeout?

Comment: Are you referring to the multiprocessing plugin timeout?

Comment: Yes I am using multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't any experience with the multiprocessing plugin but if you subclass the plugin with something like this:

```
from nose.plugins.multiprocess import MultiProcess

PLUGIN = None

class TimeoutMultiProcess(MultiProcess):
    def configure(self, options, conf):
        global PLUGIN
        PLUGIN = self
        super(TimeoutMultiProcess, self).configure(options, conf)
        if not self.enabled:
            return
```

then you can create your own test running script like:

```
import unittest


class TestA(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        from runtest import PLUGIN
        print PLUGIN.config.multiprocess_timeout

    def test_a(self):
        pass

    def test_b(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from runtest import TimeoutMultiProcess
    import nose
    nose.main(addplugins=[TimeoutMultiProcess()], defaultTest="./test.py")
```

You'll be able to change the `config.multiprocess_timeout` to different values within your tests. I'm not sure if it will work for you, but it's worth a shot.